# Apache Ambari installation issue

Tags: ambari

I'm in the process of setting up a big data environment, and I'm currently trying to install Apache Ambari by following their official documentation [https://ambari.apache.org/install.html]. However, when I execute the command [sudo rpm -Uvh http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-1.0.1.14/repos/centos6/hdp-release-1.0.1.14-1.el6.noarch.rpm], I encounter a 403 Forbidden error indicating restricted access.

I'm puzzled as to why this issue is occurring, especially since I'm following the instructions outlined in their official guide.

Have they moved to paid services?

Any advice or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I am following this guide:
https://ambari.apache.org/install.html

I have CentOS 7 on my machine.

Comment: That guide is no longer maintained / correct. Hortonworks no longer exists, and the repos aren't freely available since Cloudera took over. The links are also not for centos 7